# JSDOC datatype in @param

Tags: jsdoc3

In jsdoc @param,

```
  We can write like:
   /**
     * @param {Object} somebody- The employee who is responsible.
     */
   function sayHello(somebody: ABC) {
        alert('Hello ' + somebody);
    }
```

If I have a class like ABC and somebody is an object of type ABC, can I write it like this,?

```
   /**
     * @param {ABC} somebody- The employee who is responsible.
     */
   function sayHello(somebody: ABC) {
        alert('Hello ' + somebody);
    }
```

That is, can I give my own object type inside curly braces of param rather than giving as object? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code you are probably using TypeScript. You have 2 options:

- If ABC is an object or class you can reference it by using a JSDoc namepath (ex: myNamespaceOrModule.ABC};
- If ABC is not an actual JavaScript object (ex: a TypeScript interface) than you can use JSDoc [@typedef](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html) tag to document a custom tag.

Please, provide the code where the ABC class is defined for a better answer.